# Return data from POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm running a Flask server. A JS file send data to the server through POST requests. This is the server code:

```
@app.route('/approve', methods=['POST'])
def approve():
    try:
        assignmentId = request.form['assignmentId']
        response = client.approve_assignment(
            AssignmentId=assignmentId
        )
        return make_response(jsonify(response), response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'])
    except ClientError as e:
        return make_response(jsonify(e.response), e.response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'])
```

In JS, I want to have an alert to notify whether the action was successful or not; and if fail then what is the specific error. However, the returned data is empty and I could not check it to notify the user of specific error.

```
  $.post("http://cronus.eecs.northwestern.edu/mturk/approve", 
          {assignmentId: assignmentId,
            OverrideRejection: false}, 
          function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            if (status == 200) {
              alert("Approved successfully");
            } else {
              alert("Error");
            }
          });
```

How could I fix this? Is data null because I didn't use the correct response object in Flask code?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.fail](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for this.

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
   alert( "success" );
   })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    alert( `error ${error}` );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope this can help you.

var request = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'post',
  data: {...},
});

request.done(function(message) {
  alert(message);
});

request.fail(function(error) {
  alert(error);
});
```